# MFC program in a shared dll compiled by Visual Studio 2012 running Windows XP

Tags: c++, mfc

I have the Visual Studio 2012 with Update 5 on windows 10. I have been writing some programs which can also be run on Windows XP. I have searched some articles on how to compile a program which use MFC in a static library, and it can indeed work, but since I have been writing multi programs in a software and I want to use MFC in a shared dll. 
Although I can succeed in compiling with MFC in a shared dll, the program can not run on XP and there is an error message: “the procedure entry point InitializeCriticalSectionEx could not be located in the dynamic library KERNEL32.dll”.

Comment: That's interesting because MSDN specifically says that the function is supported on XP: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683472(v=vs.85).aspx

Do you have customers that need XP? Microsoft no longer supports it.

Comment: Sorry. I wrote the function incorrectly. The function is InitializeCriticalSectionEx and XP do not support it. I do not know how to solve this when using MFC in a shared DLL.

Comment: I tried searching the code and I could not find where MFC is using it. However, I did find where ATL is using it...and IDK if using CString might cause it to include it. However, if you #define NTDDI_VERSION NTDDI_WINXPSP2 or #define _ATL_XP_TARGETING, you might be able to solve it.

Comment: This sounds like you are trying to use the toolset for targeting XP in an unsupported way. Among others, the toolset requires you to use the Windows SDK 7.1. It also defines the `_USING_V110_SDK71_` preprocessor symbol, shadowing out the code that tries to call `InitializeCriticalSectionEx`. If you want to use a more recent SDK, you are left without official support. See [How to target XP with VC2012 or VC2013 and continue to use the Windows 8.x SDK](https://tedwvc.wordpress.com/2014/01/01/how-to-target-xp-with-vc2012-or-vc2013-and-continue-to-use-the-windows-8-x-sdk/) for more information.

Comment: It seems that I should compile it with static MFC.